# How scope of driver move in this StepDefinition class?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd

This is the StepDefinition class I am using:

```
@Given("^user is already on Login Page$")
public void user_already_on_login_page() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/ss/Downloads/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/index.html");
}

@When("^title of login page is Free CRM$")
public void title_of_login_page_is_free_CRM() {
    String title = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(title);
    Assert.assertEquals("Google", title);
}
```

If I instantiate `driver` in `"user_already_on_login_page()"` method and then how scope of `driver` moved to next method `"title_of_login_page_is_free_CRM()"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

You are initializing the driver, where as the *`driver`* declaration is within the global scope which is as:

```
WebDriver driver;
```

and should be declared at the class level with global scope.

So either of the methods *`user_already_on_login_page()`* and *`title_of_login_page_is_free_CRM()`* have access to the *`driver`* variable.